# How to get json data based on condition in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a simple json data,I need to populate it on table, based on condition.I can able to populate 'statusdata1' data based on condition.But when I populate 'statusdata2' data based on condition then its showing error. I am not getting how to get it.Can any one please help me. Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<div>
<table border="1" cellspacing="2">
 <tr *ngFor = "let x of data1">
 <td>{{x.id}}</td>
 <td>{{x.name}}</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>

 <div>
 <table border="1" cellspacing="2">
 <tr *ngFor = "let x of data1">
 <td>{{x.id}}</td>
 <td>{{x.name}}</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';

declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
imageSource :any;
statusdata1: any;
statusdata2:any;
closeResult: string;
registerForm: FormGroup;
submitted = false;
webSocketEndPoint: string = 'wss://echo.websocket.org/';
topic: string = "/topic/greetings";
stompClient: any;
mySocketData:any;
data1:any = [];

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    let statusdata1 = {"person":{"test":{"id":1,"name":"cat"}}}
    if(statusdata1.person){
        console.log(statusdata1.person);
        this.data1.push(statusdata1.person.test);
    }
    let statusdata2 = {"3":{"test":{"id":1,"name":"cat"}}}
    if(statusdata2.3){
        console.log(statusdata2.3);
        this.data1.push(statusdata2.3.test);

    }
  }

  }
```

Comment: Can someone help me is not a real question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using a number as key so you need to replace statusdata2.3 with statusdata2[3] everywhere you're using it

[Dot Notation vs. Bracket Notation](https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781)

Dot notation:
Property identifies can only be alphanumeric (and _ and $)
Property identifiers cannot start with a number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in case of multiple object how to render it into my table like {"3":{"test":{"id":1,"name":"cat"}},"4":{"test":{"id":2,"name":"dog"}}}

Answer (score 0):

As m_sultan said, you try to access to index 3 at statusdata2 or statusdata2 doesn't have this length, so you reach outer your object causing fail.

It's working for statusdata1 cause you use 'person' key and this cannot been handle as an index. So process check for person key at highlevel of statusdata1 and it's working.

But your `statusdata2.3` cause you're trying to access statusdata2 at index 3 and not what you think : access to the element key named '3'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in case of multiple object how to render it into my table like {"3":{"test":{"id":1,"name":"cat"}},"4":{"test":{"id":2,"name":"dog"}}}

Comment: If you want to access at name in theses cases, I suggest you to use only the index position of what you need. For you example, you can access to the property name of your objects by using (if your json var called statusdata) : statusdata[0][0].name (value is 'cat') and statusdata[1][0].name (or if you want ['name'] at the end), value is 'dog'. Just look at your index as the same within a array.