# How to change p-dropdown values on condition using json file in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, dropdown, primeng

My website uses three languages:

1. English
2. Sindhi
3. Arabic

I am using PrimeNG p-dropdown for selecting languages and want to change the values of p-dropdown according to if the user selects Arabic, Sindhi, or English. The default language is English.

**The problem is how to change the p-dropdown values when clicking on co-responding language.**

languages.json:

```
{
    "english": [
        
        {
            "name": "English",
            "mod": "mod3"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sindhi",
            "mod": "mod1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Arabic",
            "mod": "mod2"
        }
    ],

    "arabic": [
        
        {
            "name": "إنجليزي",
            "mod": "mod3"
        },
        {
            "name": "سنڌي",
            "mod": "mod1"
        },
        {
            "name": "عربي",
            "mod": "mod2"
        }
    ],

    "sindhi": [
        
        {
            "name": "انگريزي",
            "mod": "mod3"
        },
        {
            "name": "سنڌي",
            "mod": "mod1"
        },
        {
            "name": "عربي",
            "mod": "mod2"
        }
    ]
}
```

app.component.ts What I have tried and gotten from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60620811/how-to-get-json-data-based-on-condition-in-angular-8)

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.httpClient.get<any>('../assets/data/languages.json')
        .toPromise()
                
   
     .then((res: any) => {
            this.languages = res.english;
            localStorage.setItem('selectedLanguage', JSON.stringify(this.languages[0]));
            if(this.selectedLanguage.name === "Arabic"){
                this.languages = res.arabic;
                localStorage.setItem('selectedLanguage', JSON.stringify(this.languages[1]));
            }
            else if(this.selectedLanguage.name === "Sindhi"){
this.languages = res.sindhi;
localStorage.setItem('selectedLanguage', JSON.stringify(this.languages[2]));
}                
            
        });

 this.selectedLanguage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedLanguage")!);
}
```

app.component.html

```
<p-dropdown [options]="languages" [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage" optionLabel="name"
                (onChange)="changeLanguage(selectedLanguage)"></p-dropdown>
```

Comment: That's probably not as good idea as you might think. Imagine you're an English speaker and you've mistakingly selected Arabic in the dropdown. How do you recover from the error and switch back to English?

Comment: This is what I am trying to do! If Arabic is selected then the user can select one of three options in Arabic that will again be translated to the selected language.

Answer (score 0):

In prime ng you need to track selected value and find it in other lang array by yourself. There is an example for you:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-cnkanl)